# How do I tell my Mac to use the latest version of Python installed on my computer?

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I have updated my python version to 3.8 multiple times already via the python official website. On my mac in the terminal I type in the following command and it continues to tell me I am using 2.7.16. How can I tell my computer to stop using this old version?

```
Matthews-MBP:~ matthew$ python --version

Python 2.7.16
```

Comment: https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac  this can help you

Comment: Check your $PATH environment variable and compare it with the location where pip installed newer version of python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are the new python is installed as `python3`, `python3.8`, or `python3.8m`. Try:

```
python3 --version
python3.8 --version
python3.8m --version
```

Comment: python3.8 --version returns that I have  Python 3.8.5. How can I tell my system to use this?

Comment: How about your python3? Which version does it refer to?

Comment: I think @abdulsaboor 's link in the comment could be useful for you.

Comment: It refers to Python 3.8.5

Comment: It seems like your default shell is Bash, so run `echo "alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3.8" >> ~/.bashrc`, restart the terminal, and you are good to go :)

Comment: Oh, and if you are going to use **pip** in the future, you also want to run `echo "alias pip=/usr/local/bin/pip3" >> ~/.bashrc` (code taken from https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac, thanks abdulsaboor!)